# Angular 4 Http GET method is not working on localhost(127.0.0.1) to get JSON data

Tags: json, angular, xampp, localhost

I am trying to get JSON data from my local server that is 127.0.0.1 by using Angular 4 services, but I can't get them to my Angular App.  [I got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBGvU.png). 
[this is my JSON data on 127.0.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kts9s.png)

Note: I used XAMPP for my server [localhost (127.0.0.1)]

This is my app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {

constructor(private http: Http){}
ngOnInit()
{
this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/getdata.php?Name=json')
.subscribe(
 (res: Response)=>
 {
  const name = res.json();
  console.log("This is the response", name);
 }
 )
 }
 }
```

This is app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

 @NgModule({
 declarations: [
  AppComponent
 ],
imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 HttpModule
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling 127.0.0.1:80 from 127.0.0.1:4200 they are thought of as separate hosts. This in term means that CORS apply.

> Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows restricted resources (e.g. fonts) on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain from which the first resource was served.

To get around this proxy the requests to 127.0.0.1:80 with webpacks devserver.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

`proxy.conf.json`

`{
  "/wordpress": {
    "target": "http://localhost:80",
    "secure": false
  }
}`

and then call it from the same host

`http://localhost:4200/wordpress/getdata.php?Name=json`

Comment: Your explanation is clear, but it doesn't work for me. So I tried using my own web server that is  [link] (http://myappfact.com) and I altered my app.component.ts by ` this.http.get('http://myappfact.com/getdata.php?Name=json')`
it shows different error that is **XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myappfact.com/getdata.php?Name=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.**